# HTC Mail:  Move Messages Between Folders, Not Synced on IMAP Server

Tags: email, imap

I'm seeing some odd behavior on Android...running 2.2 on HTC Incredible.

I have an IMAP account configured through the built in "Mail" program.  First of all, when you send messages from this program, it copies them to a local "Sent" folder, and there is no way to specify a remote IMAP folder for this (e.g. "INBOX.Sent").  So then, I try to move messages manually between the local "Sent" and the IMAP "INBOX.Sent" folder, and it appears to work fine, but when I check from another IMAP client (e.g. Thunderbird), I don't see the messages in "INBOX.Sent".

Has anyone else run into this?  Any idea how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it's just not copying sent messageinto your mailbox at all, only keeping them locally.  I would assume that's just a shortcoming of the app and you'd need to use a different one that supports that feature.  The default client is very basic and buggy.  Have you considered using Gmail?  You can configure it (through the web) to get mail from an IMAP account, and then you could use the Gmail app (which is very good).

Comment: great, so assuming I switch client apps, how can I get the "trapped" emails out of my local Sent folder when moving them doesn't have any effect (except on the local device)?

Comment: Good question ... I guess you could forward them to yourself.  I'm not sure there's a simple way to get the messages themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the most excellent and customizable [K9](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fsck.k9) mail client that supports IMAP, POP3 and Exchange 2003/2007 (with WebDAV). Lots of features and its freeware too. I think you can specify folders on your server for special items like Sent, Drafts etc.

Also, it has push mail or you can configure it to poll at intervals.